# If two random variables are conditionally independent on any random variable, what will happen?

Tags: probability

If two random variables $X$ and $Y$ are conditionally independent on any random variable, what (interesting) conclusions can you draw? Thanks!

Comment: Never happens except if X and Y are constant. Thus, no interesting conclusion if "interesting" implies true and non trivial (sorry).

Comment: How do you know there are no other possibilities?

Comment: Because I looked at simple cases... Which ones did you look at yourself?

Comment: I also have looked at some simple cases, where one of $X$ and $Y$ is constant. But how can I know it won't work at cases other than the simple case you mentioned?